# Localhost problem

Tags: 12.04, lamp

I just installed Lamp recently to study wordpress. I install lamp using tasksel. But the problem is everytime i access the localhost alone, it shows this:

[image]

It says localhost/mythweb. well in the tutorial i assume that it would be like this..
[image]

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? Did you edit/create a VirtualHost entry? Do you have an `.htaccess` file in your web root directory (by default it's `/var/www`)?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/var/www/` folder. There should be a file `index.html` which is the page that shows up when you access `localhost`.

There might be a directory named `mythweb` inside `/var/www`, which is causing this.

Comment: Yes.. I saw it. Its a shortcut.. The mythweb. I think the localhost dont read the index.html. I delete the mythweb shortcute but still the same it still access the mythweb and dont read the index.html.

Comment: Please post the content of your `/etc/hosts` file.